# Pyspark: Read CSV File with no headers and variable number of columns with special characters

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a csv file with no headers and variable number of columns. I am reading the csv as text file. I have a regex to handle special characters(,-_) as well, but it seems the commas inside a single field isn't handled properly with current regex. Also, there are few values which have space after comma and my current regex is not able to handle that as well.
Example:

```
"address_line_1": "19 Woodland Grove,Warsop"
"address_line_1": "Anderson House, Street XYZ"
```

`Andrew House, Street XYZ` should be considered as one value in address_line_1.
However, the output comes like this:

```
|_c0              |        _c1|     
+-----------------+-----------+
|19 Woodland Grove|     Warsop|
|Anderson House   | Street XYZ|
```

Current Code:

```
readFile = spark.read.text("pathtoreadinputfile")
readFile = readFile.select(split(col("value"), ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)").alias("splittable_col"), "value")
sizeVar = readFile.select(max(size(col("splittable_col")))).collect()[0][0]
for i in range(sizeVar):
    readFile = readFile.withColumn("_c" + str(i), readFile['splittable_col'][i])
    df = readFile.drop("splittable_col", "value")
```

Expected Output:

```
|_c0                       |    
+--------------------------+
|19 Woodland Grove,Warsop  |
|Anderson House, Street XYZ|
```